# C wire attachment to old style lennox furnace model 80MGF3-75A-1

Tags: hvac

I am trying to install a Honneywell RTH6580WF smart thermostat that requires a C wire attached to the furnace wirning panel.  The panel has a column of wire attaching screw posts labeled Y,W,G,R  No C wire screw post... however directly underneath this screw post column  is a metal tab with a hole in it Labeled "C" that has a white wire going to the outside AC unit.
Can I use this C tab to also attach the C wire for the thermostat?

[image: furnace board]

Comment: Without picture one can not say,

Comment: I would say this is not your C point. Find the 24 volt transformer on that controll board. The 24 V hot and the C will come from it.

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring diagram on your furnace please?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, that is likely the Common wire going to the condenser. If you want confirmation, the other wire in that bundle should connect to the Y wire/terminal.

Feel free to post pics if any doubt.

EDIT: After seeing the pic posted after my original reply, it does indeed look like the common terminal. The white wire runs into a 2-wire bundle whose other wire connects to yellow.

That white wire being connected like that is not proper. Take it and add your free blue thermostat wire in a terminal connector and place it on that terminal. Your blue thermostat wire is now your C.